# Xamarin multi platform background database sync

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, background-process

I am developing an application which collects data into a local sqlite database, and (when the Internet is available) synchronises the data with a server.

I understand roughly how to create a background task (in different ways for each platform, unfortunately), but I read in [Xamarin Background Tasks](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/)...

*As a word of caution, be aware of what service or application is accessing an application, for example a SQLite DB. Two processes can not access a file at the same time, unless read-only. Hence ensure only one process is performing actions on file’s or locked resources.*

This worries me - I need both the background task and the app to be able to update a single database. Is it in fact possible for the background task and the main app to access the same database? If so, how does one go about avoiding "Database is locked" messages?

Comment: use lock statements around critical sections of your db code

Comment: But aren't background services in android running in a separate process? So lock statements wouldn't help. Plus the quote says 2 processes can't access a file at the same time unless read only - does it mean what it says, or us he just being over-cautious?

Comment: that's true, I was thinking in terms of multiple threads, not processes

Comment: @NikkiLocke Android Services do not run in a separate process unless you have specifically assigned it a different process name in the manifest.

Comment: Oh, great, I didn't realise that. Thanks.